# Clickhouse: "left join" table to external array

Tags: sql, left-join, clickhouse

Suppose there is a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE details(id String, detail_one UInt64, detail_two UInt64) ENGINE = Memory;
INSERT INTO TABLE details(id, detail_one, detail_two) VALUES ('id1', 5, 10), ('id2', 20, 30);
```

I want to be able to "left join" it to an external array of input values, so that I won't have to perform additional hash map based lookups after I get the resulting set from the database. This includes solutions that I've tried with a plain `WHERE IN` and `UNION` over this input array. Is it a bad idea in general? Can you suggest a better alternative?

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ['id1', 'id2', 'id3-missing'] AS input
LEFT JOIN details ON details.id = input;
```

So that the resulting set is as follows:

```
{
    ('id2', 5, 10), 
    ('id1', 20, 30),
    ('id3-missing', NULL, NULL) # basically return NULLs
}
```

Notes:

1. It is a rather small table: less than 10000 rows (mostly columns) and won't change much in this regard, the input array can be sized similarly.
2. It has to support extra aggregations that I'm going to perform on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [arrayJoin](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join) function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT arrayJoin(['id1', 'id2', 'id3-missing']) AS id
) AS input
LEFT JOIN details ON details.id = input.id
SETTINGS join_use_nulls = 1

/*
┌─id──────────┬─details.id─┬─detail_one─┬─detail_two─┐
│ id1         │ id1        │          5 │         10 │
│ id2         │ id2        │         20 │         30 │
│ id3-missing │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ       │       ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │       ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└─────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
*/
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM details
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT arrayJoin(['id1', 'id2', 'id3-missing']) AS id
) AS input ON details.id = input.id
SETTINGS join_use_nulls = 1

/*
┌─id──┬─detail_one─┬─detail_two─┬─input.id─┐
│ id1 │          5 │         10 │ id1      │
│ id2 │         20 │         30 │ id2      │
└─────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
┌─id───┬─detail_one─┬─detail_two─┬─input.id────┐
│ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │       ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │       ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ id3-missing │
└──────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
*/
```

---

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    input.tuple.1 AS array_id,
    input.tuple.2 AS array_value
FROM
(
    SELECT arrayJoin([('id1', 100), ('id2', 200), ('id3-missing', 300)]) AS tuple
) AS input
LEFT JOIN details ON details.id = (input.tuple.1)

/*
┌─tuple───────────────┬─id──┬─detail_one─┬─detail_two─┬─array_id────┬─array_value─┐
│ ('id1',100)         │ id1 │          5 │         10 │ id1         │         100 │
│ ('id2',200)         │ id2 │         20 │         30 │ id2         │         200 │
│ ('id3-missing',300) │     │          0 │          0 │ id3-missing │         300 │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Awesome! Both of these work just fine, what if I want to add an extra input array of values associated with these ids to be used in aggregations. I've tried adding it similarly as an arrayJoin field in the FROM, it generates extra rows even though JOINs are performed on ids.

Comment: could you provide a small example of what you have and what you want to get?

Comment: @MikhailKrassavin I added an example for this to my post. I would post it as a comment, but it's a bit harder to read that way.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you might find [arrayJoin](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join) to be helpful. It enables you to use an array in your `SELECT` statement for a subquery. So using the example info you provided, it would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT input.id, details.detail_one, details.detail_two
FROM (
  SELECT arrayJoin(['id1', 'id2', 'id3-missing']) as id
) AS input
LEFT JOIN details ON details.id = input.id;
```

So just like you posted, if `details.id` did not exist, then it would obviously return `NULL` for `detail_one` and `detail_two`.

You also mention that:

> It has to support extra aggregations that I'm going to perform on top of it.

But this should be no issue. Just be sure to add them after your join operation.

---

### Edit

I know this comment was on the other post but I figured I could help. For this question:

> Awesome! Both of these work just fine, what if I want to add an extra input array of values associated with these ids to be used in aggregations. I've tried adding it similarly as an arrayJoin field in the FROM, it generates extra rows even though JOINs are performed on ids.

You can use `arrayJoin` with a tuple like so:

```sql
SELECT input.id, input.associated_value, details.detail_one, details.detail_two
FROM (
  SELECT arrayJoin([('id1', 100), ('id2', 200), ('id3-missing', 300)]) as (id, associated_value)
) AS input
LEFT JOIN details ON details.id = input.id;
```

Comment: The added extra code didn't work on my Clickhouse setup (v23.5.3.24), still really appreciate your help.

Comment: Darn, sorry about that. Here is a link to the docs I looked at [Link](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join). At the very bottom, there is a bit about using a [tuple](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/tuple). Maybe you can interpret this better than I can.